# How to restrict an append String in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, button, append

Calling JavaScript function on delete `OnclintClick` event will give us the confirmation button message returning `Yes` when clicked `OK`.

The problem is, when clicked a second time, it will append the next String.

> ex: `Yes, Yes`

**JavaScript**

```
function Confirm() {

    var confirm_value

    confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";

    if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete supplier?")) {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
    }

    else {
        confirm_value.value = "No";
    }

    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
}
```

**Explanation**

The JavaScript Confirm method store the input provided by the user in a dynamically created hidden field i.e. if `OK` is pressed it will be stored the value `Yes` and if `Cancel` is pressed it will be stored the `No` value, so that it can pass the user inputs onto server side code.

Then It will allow the button to do normal PostBack and raise the `OnClick` event.

**Question**

How could the append be restricted to this?

Comment: Could you please create a quick snippet ? Because I dont understand your problem, so it would be easier ;) thx

Comment: You should first check to see if the input is already there, and if it is just edit the value instead of adding a new element.

Comment: Sorry @R.Foubert for did not make it clear. I am calling a JavaScript function on delete using ```OnclintClick``` event. When I clicked on code behind on delete button, it is giving me the confirm box message and when I click on ok it is returning ```Yes``` as usual. But the second time I click on Ok it is appending the string like for example: ```Yes,Yes```. My question is how could I restrict to append it?

Comment: But why do you need an innput field ? What does the "Yes" mean ? What do you try to delete exactly ? You should really provide a snippet ;) Do the answers help you or not ?

Comment: I believe the last edit answers your questions @R.Foubert. I hope so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the element an ID, and check for the ID the next time

```
function Confirm() {

    var id = "confirm_value",
        confirm_value = document.getElementById("confirm_value");

    if ( !confirm_value ) {
        confirm_value  = document.createElement("input");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = id;
        confirm_value.id   = id;

        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }

    confirm_value.value = confirm("Are you sure want to delete supplier?") ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to set a boolean flag that will be set to `true` after you set the value the first time.

```
var yourBoolean = false;
if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete supplier?")) {
        yourBoolean = true;
    if (yourBoolean === true) {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        }
    }
```